# Radio selection for each record returned from mysql db

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

On my website, I have a PHP query that returns various deli results from mysql database. For each result that is returned, I would like the same set of radio options to appear. The radio buttons will always be the same and represent how many pounds.

**An example of what I currently have**

**Returned results:**

-Roast Beef (CheckBox)

-Ham (CheckBox)

-Salami (CheckBox)

**Here is what I would like to have**

**Returned results:**

-Roast Beef (CheckBox)

- 1 (Radio)
- 2 (Radio)
- 3 (Radio)

-Ham (CheckBox)

- 1 (Radio)
- 2 (Radio)
- 3 (Radio)

-Salami (CheckBox)

- 1 (Radio)
- 2 (Radio)
- 3 (Radio)

I have one table called **deli_items**. Do I need another table that contains quantities? How would I change my PHP code?

**SELECT**

```
$sql_deli_meat="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE enabled = 1 AND ingredient_type = 'deli_meat' ORDER BY sort ASC";

$result_deli_meat=mysql_query($sql_deli_meat);
```

**PHP**

```
        <?php while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result_deli_meat)){ ?>

<input type="checkbox" name="meats[]" id="<? echo $rows['itemname']; ?>" value="<? echo $rows['label']; ?>" style="display:none;" onclick="ShowMe();" class="green-border-meats price-update"  />
<a id="<? echo $rows['itemname']; ?>" class="radio-picture-meats" href="javascript:set_radio('<? echo $rows['itemname']; ?>');"><span class="item_label"><? echo $rows['displayname'];?></span><span class="item_label_price">Per Pound<BR>$<? echo $rows['price'];?></span><img class="box" src="<? echo $rows['imagepath']; ?>" width="300px" height="215px"/></a>


        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_` functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (released in June, 2013 and so old it doesn't receive security updates anymore) and removed completely in PHP 7. Instead, use the `mysqli_` functions or PDO.

Comment: I will switch this over to mysqli at a later time

Answer (score 0):

You're already inside of your PHP tags, so you do not need to re-enter PHP when echoing rows.

This is what your updated while loop should look like:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_deli_meat)){
    $itemName = $row['itemname'];
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="meats[]" id="'$itemName'" value="'$itemName'">';
}
```

Just as a little heads up, you should **DEFINITELY** update from the older, deprecated `mysql_*` to something such as PDO or the newer MySQL improved extension. The old extension is extremely unsafe and prone to SQL injection.

Comment: How about the radio buttons?